# php pdo cant excute alter statment

Tags: php, pdo

```
public function 
updateOrderno($neworderid){    
        $updateData = array($neworderid);
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE `order` AUTO_INCREMENT=?");
    try {
        if ($stmt->execute($updateData)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        return  false;
    }
 }
```

Here is my code , I call this with $post data and then
it keep retruning false when I execute the alter statement any help?

Comment: What is `$updateData`? Also why are you twiddling the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value? That's supposed to be *automatic*.

Comment: Just have a question only . Is that alter statement work in the way I do?(pdo execute sql)

Comment: If that's a valid SQL query, which it should be, then it should execute if successfully prepared on an active connection with a valid placeholder value.

Comment: You've probably realized this by now but `order` is a MySQL reserved keyword and as such requires special treatment to use as a table or column name. That's why either avoiding that name, or using plural name conventions like `orders` helps keep things simple.